# Приложение в Битрикс24 выдает ошибку

Tags: python, flask, битрикс24

У меня на flask есть рабочий скрипт, он выдает определенную информацию, и эта информация по API загружается на битрикс24. Все работает, но я хочу встроить это приложение в сам битрикс, открыл порт через ngrok, и указал его как url обработчика в битрикс, но на выходе выдает ошибку. Кто знает, как исправить ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://t.me/bitrix24apps Вот тут спроси

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `@app.route('/urlметода', methods=['GET', 'POST'])` указать метод который используете можете сразу несколько )